# CustomButtonField in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

Plz brifly explain the meaning of ....

First i create a CustomButtonField class, and then i found out that if i din't write the

```
public boolean isFocusable() 
{
  return true;
}
```

function, it doesnot responds to user events like mouse click....

and also plz explain briefly the meaning of the following functions

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
{  
    fieldChangeNotify(0);
    return true;
}


protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time) 
{
    if (character == Keypad.KEY_ENTER) 
    {
      fieldChangeNotify(0);
      return true;
    }
    return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a field to behave like a button

- you must set `Field.FOCUSABLE` style bit.
- `setChangeListener` to CustomButtonField.

  ```
  protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
      fieldChangeNotify(0);
      return true;
  }
  ```

  if user clicks on this button, we can see that button has changed (`fieldChangeNotify(0);`)
  and listener of the button works.

  ```
  protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time) 
  {
      if (character == Keypad.KEY_ENTER) 
      {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
      }
      return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
  }
  ```

by this method if 'Enter key' pressed, button says i am changed.(`fieldChangeNotify(0);`)